# Macchanger works until connecting to network in Debian 10

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, mac-address

I’ve been trying to test out my MAC spoofing abilities on my home network using Macchanger. When not connected to WiFi, it works just fine. I can bring the interface down using ifconfig, change the mac, then bring it up again with no problems. Verifying with ifconfig shows the random ether - so I know it’s good to go.

However, when I try to connect to my WiFi, it shows the original BIA when I run ifconfig. Logging into my router shows that my BIA is also the MAC address registered - not a randomized one.

My question then is this: which default setting is causing Debian to revert to my wifi interface’s BIA instead of the address that I spoofed?

I have already tried following a couple different guides that said to try changing the NetworkManager.conf file and the 00-default.link but neither of those worked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: yes newer NetworkManager handles itself changing the mac address. check its settings, it's even in the GUI applet

Comment: I understand that there is an option for randomizing the MAC address in the GUI, but what about for connecting with a spoofed MAC address from the start?

Comment: did you check the option?

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager gained itself the ability to change the ethernet MAC addresses of interfaces it handles, and does it by default on wireless interfaces. This will override any other tool having changed the MAC address of the interface before.

Per connection settings for ethernet are prefixed with `802-3-ethernet.`, for wireless with `802-11-wireless.`. I will show an example with ethernet, and will tell about the differences with wireless after.

### Ethernet

The main setting about this for each connection is called `802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address`. Note also that `cloned-mac-address` is what is displayed by *nmcli* for compatibility reasons. The actual property is [internally named `assigned-mac-address`](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-802-3-ethernet.html). There are a few related too:

```
$ nmcli connection show id Myeth0 |grep mac # permanent MAC was redacted
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             06:05:04:03:03:01
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   --
```

`mac-address` when set  (it usually is) tells the connection applies only to the NIC with this *permanent* MAC address (as can be retrieved also with `ethtool  --show-permaddr eth0`), `mac-address-blacklist` is the opposite: to avoid a generic connection to apply to a given interface with this MAC address (obviously only one of them should be set). They aren't used for MAC spoofing settings.

So there are a few choices:

- not using NetworkManager

  but for example directly `wpa_supplicant` and a DHCP client.
- asking NetworkManager to not interfere anymore

  You can ask NetworkManager to not touch the MAC address at all:

  ```
  # nmcli connection down id Myeth0
  # nmcli connection modify id Myeth0 802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address preserve
  # ip link set eth0 down #very old NICs don't support changing MAC when up
  # ip link set eth0 address 0A:09:08:07:06:05
  # nmcli connection up id Myeth0
  ```

  The newly set MAC address will be preserved to whatever value it has currently.
- or simply letting NetworkManager do this work and not have to use an other tool before:

  ```
  $ nmcli connection modify id Myeth0 802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address 0e:0d:0c:0b:0a:09
  $ nmcli connection down id Myeth0
  $ nmcli connection up id Myeth0
  ```

  NM will now take care of changing the MAC address to the one specified.

To revert to permanent, you can set `802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address` to `permanent` (or leave it empty as this is the default for ethernet).

There are other modes like *random* or *stable* where `generate-mac-address-mask` can also be used (for example to generate a random MAC but appearing to be always from the same real manufacturer)

### Wireless

- By default, when `802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address` is empty, *random* is used.
- There's a `802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization` which might be deprecated which maybe affects the previous setting. Not very clear in documentation, but not really needed

Most of these settings are also exposed in the GUI applet. The "Cloned MAC address" field there isn't limited to a drop-down menu: you can put a MAC address in the field instead of predefined values (Preserve, Permanent, Random, Stable).

There's an additional wifi setting I don't know how to change except by editing NetworkManager's configuration files: `wifi.scan-rand-mac-address`: set to *yes* by default, it tells NetworkManager to change the MAC address of the wifi interface *when scanning*. This setting is global or per device, but not per *connection*, since there's no connection activated yet. To change it to *no* instead of *yes* you could add a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/devicewlan0.conf` looking like this:

```
[device]
match-device=interface-name:wlan0
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address:no
```

but the documentation isn't very verbose about it. Anyway this setting would be needed, perhaps, only if the 2nd option above was chosen (`preserve`) rather than the 3rd (setting a MAC address).

references:

https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-802-3-ethernet.html

https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-802-11-wireless.html

https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html (check device section)

Comment: Brilliant work @a-b. Good addendum to the limited info in the documentation. I have a question (non-native E speaker): What is the difference between permanent and preserve? What setting is closer to the MAC provided by the HW? Which one will never ever change, permanent or preserve? ?

Comment: permanent is the one usually stored in a ROM on the NIC. preserve is the previously set before NM starts any handling. My answer was also based on measures and might still have issues (eg: I now believe the ethernet default is preserve, not permanent).

Comment: thanks @A.B  ! yes, default changed: "Update-2017-01-25: with 1.6 release and newer, the default value changed from “permanent” to “preserve” [commit],[bug]."  Quote from: https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/;      MY PROBLEM: On a PC with default settings, suddenly the Ethernet NIC - MAC was changing while I was 200km away. I relied on the IPv6 - EUI64 generated IPv6 from this MAC address!!

Comment: Quite undocumented behaviour: Only last 2 or 3 packets of MAC changed.   I was not able to reproduce it. So if you use an EUI-64 MAC >> IPv6 you depend on predictable  MAC.  Thanks for your valuable hint!